# PHP zero out the time for a date and add 3 days

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm looking for an elegant/efficient way to take out the time portion of a datetime in format 'Y-m-d H:i:s', and then add 3 days.

Currently the solution is:

```
date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime("+3 days", strtotime('2017-01-23 05:32:12')));
```

where `2017-01-23 05:32:12` is the date, and this correctly outputs `2017-01-26 00:00:00`.

It just feels like there has to be a better way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: `mktime(0, 0, 0, ...sscanf('2017-01-23 05:32:12', '%3$d-%1$d-%2$d'))` will give you the zero-hour time point on the day. Just sayin'.

Comment: why not `strtotime('2017-01-23 05:32:12 +3 days')` ?

Comment: @Wizard because I had no idea you could do that, hence the question

Comment: @bishop readability is fairly important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime() offers several of ways to do this. None of them are any less verbose than your current method:

```
// Plain old DateTime()
$date = (new DateTime('2017-01-23 05:32:12'))->modify('+3 days')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');

// DateTme using DateInterval to add three days
$date = (new DateTime('2017-01-23 05:32:12'))->add(new DateInterval('P3D'))->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');

// DateTime setting the date to midnight instead of using 00:00:00
$date = (new DateTime('2017-01-23 05:32:12'))->modify('+3 days')->modify('midnight')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If the date is today you can shorten this a bit:

```
$date = (new DateTime('+3 days'))->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

Comment: No less verbose, but much more self-documenting/readable. This is what I was looking for. Don't know which answer to accept though

Comment: looks like your parentheses are unbalanced in the first 3 examples.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the heads up. I never executed the coffee so it slipped my attention.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `DateTime` class

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-01-23 05:32:12');
$date->modify('+3 days');
$outputDateString = $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

one line:

```
$date = ( new DateTime('2017-01-23 05:32:12'))->modify('+3 days')->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```